# How can I associate two tables through a foreign key that I migrated in the new database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So basically I have two tables in my old database, where Product has a foreign key referencing the SubCategory:

```
Product(ProductKey,ProductSubcategoryKey, other fields...)
ProductSubCategory(ProductSubcategoryKey, EnglishProductSubcategoryName, SpanishProductSubcategoryName,FrenchProductSubcategoryName)
```

And now I have three new tables in my new database, where CategoryID in SubCategory is a foreign key referencing Category. Both SubCategory and Category get their translation through ProductTranslation, with both getting a CategoryTranslationID:

```
SubCategory(ProductSubCategoryID,CategoryTranslationID,CategoryID)
Category(ProductCategoryID,CategoryTranslationID)
ProductTranslation(CategoryTranslationID,CategoryName_FR,CategoryName_EN,CategoryName_ES,categorytype)
```

Now, my problem here is migrating the two tables from the old database into the three new ones in the new database, while keeping their relationship intact and while migrating the hard data is not so hard, keeping their foreign key relationships is what I'm finding a big challenge and I'm stuck.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What specific challenges are you facing?  How are you attempting to migrate the data?  If you're inserting from one to another, have a look at IDENTITY_INSERT

Comment: 'DELETE FROM dbo.subCategory
INSERT INTO dbo.subCategory
           (CategoryTranslationID
           ,rowguid
           ,ModifiedDate)
SELECT a.CategoryTranslationID, NEWID(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM dbo.CategoryTranslation a
WHERE a.categoryType = 0'

Comment: I was more or less trying to use this code to migrate the data but thats doesn't keep the references in the process.

Comment: Sorry, still not quite sure what you mean by "keeping the references"?  Can you show the table definitions for the tables?  I think that would help.

Comment: Please post clear schemas, and sample data of what you have, and what you'd expect... I don't understand your new tables and how they relate to the old.

Comment: ETL with the FK ref is going to take you a LOT longer. Because db engine has to check these relationships. Your better option is to keep primary keys on each of the 3 new tables. Write your ETL to insert data into these 3 new tables. And then use sql syntax to pop FK's into place. Finally, dont forget to drop FK before next incremental load, and then re-pop FK's back on. (Hint: save the syntax by create the table structure you want with FKs then rescript to see how its enforced).